# Determine between socket and fd

Tags: c, windows, sockets, winsock, winsock2

On unix ***everything is a file*** approach of function `read()`, `write()`, `close()` is not supported on Win32.

I want to emulate it but have no idea how to distinguish when `sock` is **socket** or **fd** on WinSocks2.

```
//returns 1 if `sock` is network socket, 
//        0 if `sock` is file desriptor (including stdio, stderr, stdout), ...
//       -1 in none of above
int is_net_socket(int sock)
{
    // ...?
}
```

This should work as in :

```
int mysock  = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
int myfd    = _open("my_file.txt", _O_RDONLY);

printf("1: %d    2: %d    3: %d    4:%d\n",
       is_net_socket(mysock),   //1
       is_net_socket(myfd),     //0
       is_net_socket(stdin),    //0
       is_net_socket(stderr));  //0

// should print "1: 1    2: 0    3: 0    4:0"
```

---

How to implement `is_net_socket` in order to use it as in:

```
int my_close(int sock)
{
#if ON_WINDOWS
    switch( is_net_socket(sock) ) {
        case 1: return closesocket(sock);
        case 0: return _close(sock);
        default: //handle error...
    }
#else
    return close(sock);
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Not sure where you're getting the idea that Windows won't allow you to use `SOCKET` handles as files - as clearly stated on the [Socket Handles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740522(v=vs.85).aspx) page:

> A socket handle can optionally be a file handle in Windows Sockets 2. A socket handle from a Winsock provider can be used with other non-Winsock functions such as ReadFile, WriteFile, ReadFileEx, and WriteFileEx.

Anyways, as to *how* to distinguish between them on Windows, see the function [NtQueryObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432383(v=vs.85).aspx), which will return a handle name of `\Device\Tcp` if the handle passed to it is an open `SOCKET`. Read the "Remarks" section for the structure returned by this call.

Note that this approach only works XP and up, and will fail on Windows 2000 (which I'm assuming is old enough that it doesn't affect you.)

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you can use select to query the status of a socket.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740141%28VS.85%29.aspx

I would recommend grouping your file desc and sockets in a single struct.  You can declare an enum to tell if the descriptor is a file or socket.  I know this might not be as dynamic as you want, but generally when you create portable applications, its best to abstract those details away.

Example:

```
enum type { SOCKET, FILE };

typedef struct
{
    unsigned int id;
    type dataType;
} descriptor_t;

int close(descriptor_t sock)
{
#if WIN32
    if (sock.dataType == SOCKET)
        return closesocket(sock.id);
    else
        return _close(sock.id);
#else
    return close(sock.id);
#endif
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that way it doesn't matter what the OS's representation of files is; you are keeping track of it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect... but I am not sure, that fds and sockets on Windows use separate namespaces.  Therefore the number for a socket and a file could be the same, and it is impossible to know which one you are talking about when you call `is_net_socket`.

Try printing out socket and fd numbers to see if they are ever the same as each other at the same time.

Comment: On Windows, WinSock2 (standard since NT4) sockets are kernel object handles (File objects, either AFD or Tcp handles), which is why you can call the standard ReadFile and WriteFile functions on them. All handles to kernel objects are in the same table (per process) and don't overlap. Even if they did happen to have different implementations and different values, that could always change in the next version. Handle values should be treated as opaque.

Comment: @ChrisSmith: We're talking about `SOCKET` here, which is not a `HANDLE` last time I checked.

Comment: If you look in `winsock2.h`, there is the line `typedef UINT_PTR        SOCKET;`. That `UINT_PTR` contains an actual kernel handle. That's why you can use it with the regular file IO APIs: it wouldn't work otherwise. `SOCKET`s are sometimes called "socket handles" in the documentation for that reason.

Answer (score 3):

If the Windows 'C' library has dup() you could try to dup it, which should fail for a socket but succeed for a file fd. So:

```
int is_net_socket(fd)
{
  return close(dup(fd)) != 0;
}
```

Warning: untested theory with untested dependency ;-) Note that this would return misleading results if you run out of fd's. Another side effect is that if it is a file it will be flushed and its directory entry updated. All in all it probably sucks frankly. I might even downvote it myself.

Comment: It's good alas I really want it to be side-effect free. No other ideas? This was good begining :)

Comment: This should not have side effects. Only closing the last open file descriptor for an open file, not any file descriptor for it, should have side effects. Actually I think this solution is rather good.

Comment: @R.. It *does* have side effects. The ones I mentioned occur on Windows.

Comment: Wow that's really broken... BTW I don't think you can downvote your own answers.